# display the text as diagonally at 45 in textview

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to display my text in diagonally at 45 degree as from bottom to top. I have tried `SetRotation("45")` and `android:rotation="45"` and tried anim in xml also like this

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="20%"
        android:pivotY="20%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="line"
            android:top="1dip" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#0000" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Its not displaying in diagonally. Please help if you any idea, how to show the text in diagonally. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This worked for me

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="some text"
            android:rotation="45 "/> What was your result?

Answer (score 3):

Giving rotation of +45 degress will rotate the text from top to bottom whereas for -45 degree will rotate from bottom to top

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:rotation="-45"
            android:text="HERE"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You set can rotate runtime like this..
Make a folder like this res/anim/ and add xml file
**rotate_diagonally.xml:**

```
<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:fromDegrees="-45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="20%"
        android:pivotY="20%"  
           android:duration="0"
           android:fillAfter="true" />
```

Set runtime in your java code

```
  TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);       

  RotateAnimation rotate= (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate_diagonally);
  textview.setAnimation(rotate);
```

May it can help..